# CreateFont() from String

Tags: java, processing

It is posible to make a variable in Processing or Java that self contain the typography (ttf or otf) in format of String to be able to load it in the same way that you can do it with images, since LoadImage () works from an array of integers.
I can do it with the Images. Is there any way to do it for the case of typography?
Thanks!

```
int[][] var = {
     // R    G    B    A
     {255,   0,   0, 128},
     {  0, 255,   0, 128}
};  

PImage loadPixelsArray(int xDiv, int yDiv, float[][] dots) {

   PImage img = createImage(xDiv, yDiv, ARGB);
   img.loadPixels();
   int size = img.pixels.length;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          img.pixels[i] = color(dots[i][0], dots[i][1], dots[i][2], dots[i][3]);
   }
   img.updatePixels();
   return img;
}
```

ps: returns PImage of 2 pixels. I need the same for PFont.

Comment: So you're trying to store a font without using a font file? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to store the font in the same way that you store any other variable without relying on external files. In my example I created an image from an array of pixels instead of an external image file. I want to do the same but with a typography.

Comment: Right, I understand what you're saying. I'm asking **why** you want to do this?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I wanna share a game whitout any external file in the data folder. Nothing more than my exe file. It is posible in processing? ps: i saw your Happy Coding project, respect!

Comment: Note that the Processing export doesn't give you a proper `.exe` file. It gives you a directory with a run script. If you want to create a singular `.exe` file, you'll have to convert the whole directory into a `.exe` file. Trying to eliminate the font file will not give you a `.exe` file.

Comment: Ok, thanks Kevin, I'm going to take your answer as a possible way to face the problem but it's really not what I'm looking for and I do not think it's something that can not be done.

Answer (score 0):

In the Processing editor go to **Tools > Create Font..** to create a .vlw file (Processing's font format) then in your code simply use [loadFont()](https://processing.org/reference/loadFont_.html) instead of `createFont()`

[image: CreateFont tool preview]

Be sure to run some tests in terms of the right font size and characters (especially if using special characters). In terms of rendering text Processing can do bitmaps or shapes using [textMode()](https://processing.org/reference/textMode_.html) depending on the renderer.

Additionally, if you need to create images/pixels of text you can use [PGraphics](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) (which extends `PImage`)

**Update**
It is still unclear what is that you're asking:

- loading a font from a string(font filename) ?
- render text to an image ?
- get all the gyphs in a font as pixels ? something else ?

If you want to render text to an image, as mentioned above you can use PGraphics:

```
noSmooth();

PGraphics textImage = createGraphics(25,25);
textImage.beginDraw();
textImage.text("O!",10,15);
textImage.endDraw();

image(textImage,0,0);
image(textImage,0,0,textImage.width * 2.1,textImage.height * 2.1);
image(textImage,0,0,textImage.width * 4.5,textImage.height * 4.5);
```

[image: text rendered to image]

For more details on PFont use the [PFont javadoc](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PFont.html).
Notice you can [get glyphs](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PFont.html#getGlyph-char-) ([which have images](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PFont.Glyph.html)):

```
String[] fontNames = {"Monospaced","ProcessingSansPro-Regular"};
int NUM_FONTS = fontNames.length;
PFont[] fonts = new PFont[NUM_FONTS];
PFont font;

int FONT_SIZE = 30;
String message = "Hello World";

ArrayList<PImage> glyphImages;

void setup(){
  size(300,300);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill(0);
  
  // load fonts
  for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_FONTS; i++){
    fonts[i] = createFont(fontNames[i],FONT_SIZE);
  }
  
  // set first font
  setFont(0);
  
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  text(message,width * 0.5,height * 0.5);
  
  drawGlyphImages();
  
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == '1'){
    setFont(0);
  }
  if(key == '2'){
    setFont(1);
  }
}

void setFont(int fontIndex){
  // check font data is accessible
  if(fonts != null){
    
    if(fontIndex >= 0 && fontIndex < fonts.length){
      
      // update global reference to currently set font
      font = fonts[fontIndex];
      // tell Processing to use this font
      textFont(font,FONT_SIZE);
      // create glyph images
      glyphImages = getGlyphImages(font,message);
      
    }else{
      println("error: invalid array index",fontIndex,"valid range is",0,fonts.length-1);
    }
    
  }else{
    println("error: null fonts array");
  } 
}

ArrayList<PImage> getGlyphImages(PFont font,String message){

  ArrayList<PImage> result = new ArrayList<PImage>();
  
  // access font glyph images
  for(int i = 0 ; i < message.length(); i++){
    
    // get the each character
    char currentChar = message.charAt(i);
    // get the glyph
    PFont.Glyph glyph = font.getGlyph(currentChar);
    // if there is a glyph (space or other special character might not be encoded in the font file)
    if(glyph != null){
      // get a copy of the glyph image
      PImage glyphImage = glyph.image.get();
      // glyph PImages are in ALPHA format: for demo purposes we use a GRAY filter to set the format to RGB  
      glyphImage.filter(GRAY);
      // append the glyph image to the list
      result.add(glyphImage);
    }
    
  }
  
  return result;
}

ArrayList<PShape> getGlyphShapes(PFont font,String message){

  ArrayList<PShape> result = new ArrayList<PShape>();
  
  // access font glyph images
  for(int i = 0 ; i < message.length(); i++){
    
    // get the each character
    char currentChar = message.charAt(i);
    // get the glyph shape
    PShape glyphShape = font.getShape(currentChar);
    // if there is a glyph (space or other special character might not be encoded in the font file)
    if(glyphShape != null){
      // add the shape to the list
      result.add(glyphShape);
    }
    
  }
  
  return result;
}

void drawGlyphImages(){
  float previousGlyphsHeight = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < glyphImages.size(); i++){
    PImage glyphImage = glyphImages.get(i);
    image(glyphImage,10,glyphImage.height + previousGlyphsHeight,glyphImage.width * 2,glyphImage.height * 2);
    previousGlyphsHeight += (glyphImage.height * 2) + 3;
  }
}
```

[image: PFont glyph images font 1]

[image: PFont glyph images font 2]

Additionally you can get the shapes via PFont's [`getShape()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PFont.html#getShape-char-):

```
String[] fontNames = {"Monospaced","ProcessingSansPro-Regular"};
int NUM_FONTS = fontNames.length;
PFont[] fonts = new PFont[NUM_FONTS];
PFont font;

int FONT_SIZE = 30;
String message = "Hello World";

ArrayList<PShape> glyphShapes;

void setup(){
  size(345,345);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill(0);
  
  // load fonts
  for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_FONTS; i++){
    fonts[i] = createFont(fontNames[i],FONT_SIZE);
  }
  
  // set first font
  setFont(0);
  
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  text(message,width * 0.5,height * 0.5);
  
  drawGlyphShapes();
  
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == '1'){
    setFont(0);
  }
  if(key == '2'){
    setFont(1);
  }
}

void setFont(int fontIndex){
  // check font data is accessible
  if(fonts != null){
    
    if(fontIndex >= 0 && fontIndex < fonts.length){
      
      // update global reference to currently set font
      font = fonts[fontIndex];
      // tell Processing to use this font
      textFont(font,FONT_SIZE);
      // update glyph shapes
      glyphShapes = getGlyphShapes(font,message);
    }else{
      println("error: invalid array index",fontIndex,"valid range is",0,fonts.length-1);
    }
    
  }else{
    println("error: null fonts array");
  } 
}

ArrayList<PShape> getGlyphShapes(PFont font,String message){

  ArrayList<PShape> result = new ArrayList<PShape>();
  
  // access font glyph images
  for(int i = 0 ; i < message.length(); i++){
    
    // get the each character
    char currentChar = message.charAt(i);
    // get the glyph shape
    PShape glyphShape = font.getShape(currentChar);
    // if there is a glyph (space or other special character might not be encoded in the font file)
    if(glyphShape != null){
      // add the shape to the list
      result.add(glyphShape);
    }
    
  }
  
  return result;
}

void drawGlyphShapes(){
  float maxGlyphHeight = 30;
  for(int i = 0; i < glyphShapes.size(); i++){
    PShape glyphShape = glyphShapes.get(i);
    glyphShape.disableStyle();
    noFill();
    beginShape();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < glyphShape.getVertexCount(); j++){
      PVector vertex = glyphShape.getVertex(j);
      vertex(10 + vertex.x,vertex.y + 30 + glyphShape.getHeight() + (maxGlyphHeight * i));
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

[image: PFont glyph shapes font 1]

[image: PFont glyph shapes font 2]

If you want to draw your own glyphs you can always use [beginShape()](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html), [createShape()](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html), etc. and wrap it in a function that takes the string you want to render and draws the correct shapes for each character.

If you want to create your own ttf font file you may need an external library.
Have a look at the [Typography Processing libraries](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/#typography) for extended functionality.

Comment: I had seen that option but it had not occurred to me that it would work for this. I just did what you suggest and I'm seeing that the output is in binary. Is there any way to export in the form of ASCII strings? My original idea is to be able to assign it to a variable within my code and not depend on any eternal file. As follows:

String var = "typography data, typography data, typography data ... etc ...";

Comment: @NazimMoises It's not clear what you mean by typography data. "ps: returns PImage of 2 pixels. I need the same for PFont." is even more confusing. By confusing data do you mean the actual vector paths for each text character in a string ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this without resorting to some pretty gross hacks.

If you're curious, the way you might approach this is by first creating a `.vlw` font using George's answer. Then you'd need to write a utility program that reads in the bytes of the file as a byte array, then outputs some syntax that lets you store this as a variable. Copy that variable into your target sketch, and then you could then use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to pass the bytes into the `PFont` constructor that takes an `InputStream`.

So sure, it's **possible** to do this. But this is very hacky and you should definitely not bother trying it.

Instead, I encourage you to take a step back and think about exactly what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're trying to export a single `.exe` file from Processing. Note that this is not possible, even if you use the above hack to get rid of the font file!

Processing exports itself as a directory of run scripts and `.jar` files. It is **not** a single packaged executable file. To convert your Processing sketch into a `.exe` file, you're going to have to use something like Launch4J or JWrapper.

Note that these kinds of applications all offer support for packaging external files, which is how you should deal with your font file.

Also note that you could just store your font on the web, and then pass the URL into the `loadFont()` function. But again, you'll still have to deal with the multiple `.jar` files that Processing exports.

Comment: Kevin, I understand your suggestions perfectly. A pity, I thought it was something simple to perform as in the case of PImage. My idea was to do it with the sound, but I will have to look for other ways or to post the path that you indicate within a suitable topic. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @NazimMoises I'm pretty sure you're trying to solve something that isn't an actual problem. It doesn't make a ton of sense to include a file as a string, and using it as a file should work fine. If your end goal is to create a single `.exe` file, there are better ways to do that.